# XBAP Exception Notifier

Tags: xbap

I'm planning to design an exception notifier which is in an XBAP application (Partial Trust). The exception notifier will be a user control. It will consist of a list box on the left side with all the error messages and a detailed explanation of that error message on the right hand side which will be another listbox (templated one).

I do not want to show this exception notifier every time to the user. When there is an error/exception, this hidden exception notifier must pop up from the bottom of my screen (or from any direction) with some animation. Users can then have an option to close the exception notifier when they have finished viewing the message.

Any code sample will help me out.

Answer (score 0):

dude check out

[Dealing with unhandled exceptions in WinForms](http://srtsolutions.com/blogs/mikewoelmer/archive/2009/04/17/dealing-with-unhandled-exceptions-in-winforms.aspx)

[Dealing with unhandled exceptions in WPF](http://srtsolutions.com/blogs/mikewoelmer/archive/2009/04/17/dealing-with-unhandled-exceptions-in-wpf.aspx)

Also have a look at [Exception Reporter](http://exceptionreporter.codeplex.com/)